# Creating form from template with VBA in Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I'm using this row to create a form from a template in MS Access:

```
Set frm = CreateForm(, "MallFrm")
```

The `MallFrm` contains buttons but these buttons don't appear in the new form.

How to get buttons created in a new form from the template form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a new form based on a template form, the new form inherits style properties from the template but does not copy control objects from the template.

For your purpose, use `DoCmd.CopyObject` to create a copy of the template and continue your design work using the copy.

```vb
DoCmd.CopyObject NewName:="NewForm", SourceObjectType:=acForm, SourceObjectName:="MallFrm"
DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="NewForm", View:=acDesign
Set frm = Forms!NewForm
```